# Expanding dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have the following data in R:

| Group | Dummy_N | Total_N | Other val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | x |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | y |

I want to expand this data so that there are Total_N number of rows with Dummy_N number of 1s.Like:

| Group | Dummy_N | Total_N | Other val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | x |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | x |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | x |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | x |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | y |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | y |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | y |

I am able to expand it with the following code:

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$Total_N), 1:4]
```

But I am struggling to implement making the Dummy N which corresponds to the number in Dummy_N in the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option in `tidyverse` would be to expand the data with `uncount` (similar to `rep(...)` in `base R`), then convert the 'Dummy_N' column to binary by creating a logical vector with the sequence (`row_number()`) and its value, grouped by 'Group' column

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  uncount(Total_N, .remove = FALSE) %>%
   mutate(Dummy_N = +(row_number() <= Dummy_N), .by = Group)
```

-output

```
   Group Dummy_N Total_N Otherval
1     1       1       4        x
2     1       0       4        x
3     1       0       4        x
4     1       0       4        x
5     2       1       3        y
6     2       1       3        y
7     2       0       3        y
```

---

For earlier versions of `dplyr`, use `group_by/ungroup`

```
df %>%  
    uncount(Total_N, .remove = FALSE) %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(Dummy_N = +(row_number() <= Dummy_N)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  Group Dummy_N Total_N Otherval
  <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>   
1     1       1       4 x       
2     1       0       4 x       
3     1       0       4 x       
4     1       0       4 x       
5     2       1       3 y       
6     2       1       3 y       
7     2       0       3 y
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
out <- transform(df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Total_N),],
   Dummy_N =  ave(Dummy_N, Group, FUN = function(x) 
   seq_along(x) <= x))
```

-output

```
out 
     Group Dummy_N Total_N Otherval
1       1       1       4        x
1.1     1       0       4        x
1.2     1       0       4        x
1.3     1       0       4        x
2       2       1       3        y
2.1     2       1       3        y
2.2     2       0       3        y
```

The row names can be set to NULL afterwards

```
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Group = 1:2, Dummy_N = 1:2, Total_N = 4:3, Otherval = c("x", 
"y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: It is only working for the first group but not the later groups. This is the code I have there.
```df_expanded<- df %>% 
  uncount(Reach, .remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(Results = +(row_number() <= Results), .by = group_id)```

Comment: @SwaroopPoudel Do you have the latest version as I suggested 1.1.0 for dplyr.  If not, use `df %>% 
  uncount(Total_N, .remove = FALSE) %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Dummy_N = +(row_number() <= Dummy_N)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @SwaroopPoudel This is one issue - if we use the latest version code, it would have an issue, then we switch to older one, it may get deprecated and not much use in future.  So, I try to use the latest version code

Comment: I used the updated code and it worked well. Thank you very much!